# This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type 'a list

Tags: ocaml

I want to count how many "u"s are in a list. An example of the function call would be

```
     countu(["u"; "a"; "x"], 0);;
        :-int = 1
```

The code I have is

```
let rec countu = fun(x, y) ->
    if List.length (List.hd x) == 0 then y
    else if List.hd x == "u" then countu(List.tl x, y+1)
    else countu(List.tl x, y);;
```

I understand why I'm getting the problem. Ocaml wants a 'a list, but because I am comparing it to a string, it makes it a string. It will also get mad when I recall countu with y+1, because again, it wants a non-specified unit instead of an integer. How do I get around this. I want the signature to look like

```
val countups : string list * int -> int = <fun>
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the `x` and `y` arguments of the function? In particular, I don't understand why you need `y` (an int) to find the number of `"u"` in the list. Shouldn't the function signature be `val count_u : string list -> int`?

Comment: x is the list passed in, y is number returned. We are not allowed to make new variables, so it has to be passed in with the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
if List.length (List.hd x) == 0 then ...
```

But this only makes sense if `x` is a list of lists. Your `x` is a list of strings.

Possibly what you want is just this:

```
if List.length x = 0 then ...
```

As a side comment, the equality comparison operator in OCaml is `=`. The `==` operator is for special cases, and you shouldn't use it without having a good reason.

Comment: You should never do `List.length x = 0`, it's O(len), while `match x with [] -> .. | _ -> ...` is constant time.